# LAN Python Server

Tags: python, server, lan

How is creating a server using python only for LAN different from one which is open across networks?Is the difference only in the host address?
Please elaborate on how socket family and type should be set for a LAN based server in python..

Comment: Normally, unless you're the gateway, the procedure on the client is the same. The difference is whether the gateway sets up a port forward or similar to let external clients connect.

Comment: @TomHunt So u r saying that the socket family and type don't really differ as compared to that for a general socket...?

Comment: @TomHunt If the server is set as a gateway to connect 2 clients, can I use the same port to move data across? As even though the port would be the same, the source and destination address would be different..It would work right?